# Flex NumericStepper: limit range of integer part before the decimal point

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, numericstepper

I have a NumericStepper in flex that must accept values between 0 and 999.99.

I tried setting the numericStepper as follows:

```
    <s:NumericStepper id="numStepper" value="@{myValue}" maximum="999.99" snapInterval="0.01" stepSize="0.01" minimum="0"/>
```

and setting also a NumberValidator attached to it:

```
var nValidator:NumberValidator = new NumberValidator();
nValidator.source = numStepper;
nValidator.precision = 2;
numericStepper.maxChars=6;
nValidator.decimalSeparator=".";
```

The thing works but I would like also to directly limit the user input via keyboard in the numeric stepper, so that the user can't type things like "1.4567" but only 1.45.

So I want something to limit the integer and decimal part of the number according to my specifications:

1. max 3 chars integer part
2. "." decimal separator
3. max 2 chars precision

Maybe some regular expression can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried...

```
nValidator.fractionalDigits = 2;
```

Comment: I think fractionalDigits is not available in Flex 4, (the one I'm using).

Comment: @frankieta according to the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/validators/supportClasses/NumberValidatorBase.html#fractionalDigits), fractionalDigits is available in the Flex 4 (Spark) `NumberValidator` class. **Edit:** Doh, I guess you may not be using Flex 4.5 (where this property was added ... sorry should have read the docs more closely)

Comment: I think this may be overkill, but you could create a "MyNumericStepper" class which extends the spark NumericStepper and then override the "value" setter property to always round to double precision. Then in your MXML, use `<mynamespace:MyNumericStepper />`

Comment: ... or further overkill, download the source for Flex 4.5's NumberValidator and compile it yourself as a class within your project. Unsure how realistic this is.

Comment: @SunilD. yes I'm not using flex 4.5 :(


Thanks for your comment Kaushal, I think it's the only way to go but I will stuck with the current implementation, it's correct anyway, just slightly confusing for the user.